# URL helpers for member routes are undefined in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

After adding three custom member routes, everything works fine in the development and production environments, but fails in the testing environment.

In `config/routes.rb`, our custom member routes are copy, download and abort:

```
resources :kw_researches do
  member do
    get 'copy'
    get 'download'
    put 'abort'
  end
end
```

Running `rake routes` shows the member routes are all fine and dandy (not a big surprise, as they actually work in production and development):

```
$ rake routes
    copy_kw_research GET    /kw_researches/:id/copy(.:format)     kw_researches#copy
download_kw_research GET    /kw_researches/:id/download(.:format) kw_researches#download
   abort_kw_research PUT    /kw_researches/:id/abort(.:format)    kw_researches#abort
       kw_researches GET    /kw_researches(.:format)              kw_researches#index
                     POST   /kw_researches(.:format)              kw_researches#create
     new_kw_research GET    /kw_researches/new(.:format)          kw_researches#new
    edit_kw_research GET    /kw_researches/:id/edit(.:format)     kw_researches#edit
         kw_research GET    /kw_researches/:id(.:format)          kw_researches#show
                     PUT    /kw_researches/:id(.:format)          kw_researches#update
                     DELETE /kw_researches/:id(.:format)          kw_researches#destroy
```

But the tests in both `./spec/views/kw_researches/index.html.erb_spec.rb` and `./spec/integration/kw_research_index_page_spec.rb` fail with errors such as the following:

```
  10) KwResearch index page KwResearch has all relevant actions
     Failure/Error: visit kw_researches_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `copy_kw_research_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faab8c9a238>:0x007faab717fd40>
```

Why is `copy_kw_research_path` not available, while its good (standard helper) friend `edit_kw_research_path` is? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we returned to the problem two weeks later, it just disappeared: It would appear that restarting both the rails server (thin) and guard solved it.